# Java Array.Out.Of.Bound exception

Tags: java, arrays

I have a huge problem I can not understant why this part of code  throws this exception because I can not see where I get out of my array bound?
I want to derive a polinom with int coeff and positive powers. i save my powers in an array iPower and my coeff in iCoefficient. in my polinom class iMaxPower gives my the highest fower of my polinom.

```
public int DerivePolinom(Polinom p1, Polinom p2)//operation class
    {
        int i,count=0;
        i=p1.iMaxPower;

        while(i>0)
        {
            if(p1.iPower[i]==1)// here is my exception!
            {
                p2.iPower[i]=1;//I know it does not derive my polinom 
                p2.iCoefficient[i]=p1.iCoefficient[i];
                count++;// use this to know the nr of the result polinom terms

            }
            i++;
        }

        return count;
     }



int iDegreeMax=0;//main class
           System.out.print("Enter the polinom: number of terms-power-coefficient \n");
            Polinom p1 = new Polinom();//create my polinom object
            iDegree=sc.nextInt();//read the numbers of terms
            p1.readPolinom(iDegree);//read my polinom
            p1.printPolinom(p1,iDegree); 

            Operation o = new Operation();//create operation object
            Polinom p2 = new Polinom();//we create another polinom object to pun the result in
            iDegreeMax=o.DerivePolinom(p1,p2);
            System.out.print("\nThe derivation of the polinom is: ");
            p2.printPolinom(p2,iDegreeMax);
```

Comment: Please provide a list of values you are using to generate the error you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop, there is nothing to make the loop exit,
so the value of `i` will keep increasing,
until eventually it goes beyond the bound of `p1.iPower`.

> ```
>     while(i>0)
>     {
>         if(p1.iPower[i]==1)// here is my exception!
>         {
>             p2.iPower[i]=1;//I know it does not derive my polinom 
>             p2.iCoefficient[i]=p1.iCoefficient[i];
>             count++;// use this to know the nr of the result polinom terms
>
>         }
>         i++;
>     }
> ```

You need to add a condition either inside the `while` statement itself,
or inside the loop body to break out of it. This might work for example:

```
    while (i > 0 && i < p1.iPower.length)
```

Comment: lol I see it not there should be i--  sorry to many  hours in front of computer:(